# Registering an HTML-derived content type with the HTML editor without a package?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsx, visual-studio-sdk, languageservice

I'm trying to register a custom content type, similar to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9575a69d-33b5-4129-b301-d26a6f745255/how-do-i-derive-content-type-and-file-extension-from-existing-ones) on MSDN forums: I want to register a custom extension that is essentially an HTML file, e.g.:

```
[Export]
[DisplayName("My Custom Markup")]
[Name("mycustom")
[BaseDefinition("html")]
internal static ContentTypeDefinition MyCustomContentType;

[Export]
[FileExtension(".mycustom")]
[ContentType("mycustom")]
internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition MyCustomFileExtensionDefinition;
```

So by specifying `BaseDefinition` as `html`, I am able to get HTML highlighting in `.mycustom` files, unfortunately I get nothing else, in particular, the HTML intellisense. From the above link it seems that the only way to have Visual Studio recognize custom extensions as a specific editor type, but I'd have to hack the registry (or more specifically, provide this via the `ProvideEditorExtension` attribute, but it's only applicable on a VSPackage).

So my question is, basically, is there an alternative way to register a custom extension to an editor programmatically, but without creating a custom VSPackage for it? Other than hacking the registry, of course?

(I could be totally wrong with the approach, in which case your help is very much appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the technique demoed here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/01/new-extension-css-is-less.aspx

This is effectively "hacking the registry" but in a supported way. You're simply wrapping the needed keys in a .pkgdef file (essentially a .reg file) that can be contained in an editor extension.

Comment: Of course! It totally escaped me that a pkgdef doesn't require an actual package implementation! Thanks!

Comment: Heh, found this old twitter chat :) https://twitter.com/Schabse/status/390564739081728000

Comment: Yeah, the name is somewhat misleading. :-)

Comment: Yup, though it turned out I really *did* need an empty package. VSIX project will not compile (pkgdefgen.exe will throw an error), if there's a .pkgdef file in the project, but no VSPackage (more specifically, `[PackageRegistration]` attribute in the project). So I created an empty package, add even registered my custom type programmatically: `[ProvideEditorExtension(VSConstants.VsEditorFactoryGuid.HtmlEditor_string, ".mycustom", 0x28)]`

Comment: You can just set <GeneratePkgDefFile>false</GeneratePkgDefFile> to disable the auto generation of one.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, I'll try that :) Though frankly, using attributes makes it less "magic". But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Funny, we often consider the attributes "too magic" since you don't actually know what they're doing. All the attributes do is generate a pkgdef.